# AWS DotNetCore Lambda - Multiple Project in one solution

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am trying to publish a .net core 3 web api project using a serverless template. To publish the Lambda I am using Code Pipeline to call "AWS CloudFormation Package" on the serverless template to get the code into S3 so it can be published as a Lambda.

The visual studio solution is split into two projects, one DotNetCore Lambda function, and a supporting .net standard class library which is referenced by the main project. When the package step is run only the code for the first project is zipped into S3 and not the dependant class library meaning the lambda fails to run.

It is not clear to me how to tell the serverless template it must include the code in both projects?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was being a little special and I was packaging source code and not compiled code. I added a dotnet publish step to the build process and pointed the cloudformation package at the published output and all was good.